# Azure CDN 504 Gateway Timout on ECAcc servers

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I am using old cdn azXXXXvo.msecnd.net. Sometimes I have 504 Gateway Timeout, region is East US, the 504 usually came from ECAcc servers which are POP Geolocated Cache servers as I understood. The 504 occurs very often in East US when in Europe it almost not happening. I have checked Azure status, but they saying that everything is 100% ok in all regions. What can I do with it?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old Q, but.

We faced with the same 504 using Prem Verizon CDN. The issue was in firewall - our (Dev env) application had limited networks allowed for access.

Thus solution was - add all nets from this list:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt757330.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396